# Multi threading nodeJS and Socket IO

Tags: node.js, multithreading, sockets

Okay so multithreading nodeJS isn't much problem from what I've been reading. Just deploy several identical apps and use `nginx` as reverse proxy and load balancer of all the apps.

But actually native `cluster` module works pretty well too, I found.

However, what if I have `socket.io` with the `nodeJS` app? I have tried the same strategy with `nodeJS + socket.IO`; however, it obviously did not work because every socket event emitted will be more or less evenly distributed and sockets other than the one that made the connection would have no idea where the request came from.

So best method I can think of right now is to separate `nodeJS` server and `socket.IO` server. Scale `nodeJS` server horizontally (multiple identical apps) but just have one `socket.IO` server. Although I believe it would be enough for the purpose of our solution, I still need to look out for future. Has anyone succeeded in horizontally scaling `Socket.IO`? So multiple threads?

Answer (score 1):

The guidelines on the socket.io website use Redis with a package called `socket.io-redis`

https://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/

Looks like is just acts like a single pool for the connections, and each node instance connects to that.

Putting your socket server on a separate service (micro-service) is a probably fine, the downside is needing to manage communications between the two instances.

Comment: It is slightly outdated but http://www.farennikov.com/2013/06/scaling-socket-io-with-node-js-cluster/#.WmlBu6iWaUk says that redis solution does not work. Have you tried this methodology before?